# Overriding navbar styles in less file of bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would to customize bootstrap styles using less files. Here I want  to override navbar styles. Currently I am doing... (in custom-bootstrap.less file)

```
@import "../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "../bootstrap/less/responsive.less";
@import "custom-variables.less"; 
.navbar{
.navbar-inner{
    background:none;
    background-color: @navBGColor;
    border-bottom: darken(@navBGcolor, 15%);
  }
}
```

**I have tried different styles in .navbar-inner nothing is happening there.**

What's wrong with code?